# Unable to deploy to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed to firebase hosting,
after that

I want to delete the duplicate deployed
but I couldn't find a way to delete the hosting

so what I did,

I used firebase deploy hosting:disable sample-project
and I deleted all rollback in the console

now I have no way to re-deploy it.

any one knows how to revive my google deploy?

or the only way to revive it is just create another project and abandon this one ?

Comment: what does your firebase console show?

Comment: no error, it shows that the roll back has been deleted and the webhosting is disabled

Comment: i guess you'd have to delete the current hosting and init another one

Comment: that's the problem I can't, when I try to delete the hosting, it's keep on saying that there's no such project, if though I could I see one

Comment: let the current hosting be there, create another project/add another site.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but I hate Bload in my project zz